# Dynamically Map Class Entity x Database Table (Spring-Data/SpringBoot)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 12 (each table represents 1 month of moving records. We usually do this for a single table not composing millions of records) tables in my postgresql database, following example:

movprodXXZZ
where: XX => month
and : ZZ => Year

movprod0121
movprod0221
movprod0321

Therefore, I need to map these tables dynamically, as they are automatically created by the system's ERP, using

```
 "CREATE TABLE"
```

as soon as the month in question starts. In fact the columns don't change, they are the same, but the table name is changeable.

How do I in Spring-Data to solve this problem and dynamically pass the table name?

Comment: what did you try so far?